# Static linking of an FORTRAN code with MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi, static-linking, intel-fortran

I want to build a standalone bainary (static linking) of my fortran code so that it does not use any shared libaries anymore.
The program uses mpi so I need all connected libaries.
I started with generating my own libary pack:

```
ar rc my_lib.a /opt/intel/impi/4.1.0.030/intel64/lib/* /opt/intel/composerxe/mpirt/lib/intel64/*
```

Followed by compiling my files:

```
ifort -c -I/home/.../Remote/mpif.h -L/home/../Remote/my_lib.a file1.f
ifort -c -I/home/.../Remote/mpif.h -L/home/.../Remote/my_lib.a file1.f

ifort -O3 -o dns zufall.o dnspipe.o my_lib.a
```

But this returned the following error message:

```
ld: dns: hidden symbol `stat' in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS) is referenced by DSO
ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

How could I fix that?

Remark 1: @Gilles
I tried that now and it works:

```
mpiifort -c zufall.f
mpiifort -c dnspipe.f

ifort -o dns zufall.o dnspipe.o -L/opt/intel/impi/4.1.0.030/intel64/lib -Wl,-non_shared,-lmpigf,-lmpi,-lmpigi,-call_shared
```

The `ldd dns` output than is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6ace6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f557a6f9000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f557a4dd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f557a151000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5579f3b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5579d37000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f557a993000)
```

Is this now static?

Comment: You could also take a look at the flag `-static_mpi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the same version of Intel MPI so I can't test for sure my solution here. But still, here is how it goes after a few remarks:

- Having a fully static binary might not be such a good idea, especially when it comes to the libc... But on a fully homogeneous cluster, why, not.
- Normally, just using `mpiifort -static` should do the trick. However, experience shows that this is rarely the case because of some random functions missing here and there in the static libs, etc.
- If only some of the libraries are the ones you want to have statically linked, then there is a solution. If for example this is the Intel libraries you want static, the `-intel-static` linking option is supposedly doing the tick. But again, unfortunately, most of the time it doesn't work as advertised, notably for the MPI libraries.

So let's assume that what you want is at least packing the MPI libraries into your binary. So this is how I do it:

```
> mpiifort -c hello_mpi.f90
> ifort -o hello_mpi hello_mpi.o -L$INTEL_MPI_PATH/intel64/lib -Wl,-non_shared,-lmpigf,-lmpi,-lmpigi,-call_shared
```

The list of libraries to include will depend on the version of the MPI library you use I guess, but you can easily get it with a `mpiifort -show`.

This works for me. Does it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don' have the env. variable $INTEL_MPI_PATH is there a script which gives me the variabel or did you set that yourself? I tried to execute the `./opt/intel/impi/4.1.0/bin/mpivars.sh` which did not set the variable.

Comment: Well, IDK exactly where I get it from, but ultimately, you can replace it by /opt/intel/impi/4.1.0.030/ in your case, which would give: `ifort -o hello_mpi hello_mpi.o -L/opt/intel/impi/4.1.0.030/intel64/lib -Wl,-non_shared,-lmpigf,-lmpi,-lmpigi,-call_shared`

Comment: You missed the `intel64` bit of the path.

Comment: Thank that did the trick! I change it in my question! But when I use ldd on my binary I still see some links does that mean it is not static (I put the output in the question aswell)? And there is no static flag in the command do I miss something?

Comment: No, the code is not fully static, but the only dynamic libraries you've got here are some system-related ones, which you can/should better keep dynamic.
In any case, all MPI-related functions are now embedded into your binary, which is I suspect what you wanted.